# Unawaited promises still executed

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

While debugging a set-up to control promise concurrency for some CPU intensive asynchronous tasks, I came across the following behavior that I can not understand.

My route to control the flow was to first create an array of Promises, and after that control the execution of these Promises by explicitly awaiting them. I produced the following snippet that shows the unexpected behavior:

```
import fs from 'node:fs';
import { setTimeout } from 'node:timers/promises';

async function innerAsync(n: number) {
  return fs.promises.readdir('.').then(value => {
    console.log(`Executed ${n}:`, value);
    return value;
  });
}

async function controllerAsync() {
  const deferredPromises = new Array<Promise<string[]>>();

  for (const n of [1, 2, 3]) {
    const defer = innerAsync(n);
    deferredPromises.push(defer);
  }

  const result = deferredPromises[0];
  return result;
}

const result = await controllerAsync();
console.log('Resolved:', result);

await setTimeout(1000);
```

This snippet produces the following result (assuming 2 files are in `.`):

```
Executed 1: [ 'test.txt', 'test2.txt' ]
Resolved: [ 'test.txt', 'test2.txt' ]
Executed 2: [ 'test.txt', 'test2.txt' ]
Executed 3: [ 'test.txt', 'test2.txt' ]
```

**Observed**

The promises defined at line 15 are all being executed, regardless if they are returned/awaited (2 and 3).

**Question**
What causes the other, seemingly unused, promises to be executed? How can I make sure in this snippet only the first Promise is executed, where the others stay pending?

---

- Node v19.2
- Typescript v4.9.4
- [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-zjinz2?file=index.ts)

Comment: (Oooh, hadn't seen `node:timers/promises`. Nice!)

Comment: (also just learned about it :) Seems Node is adding more and more native QoL libraries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promises aren't "executed" at all. A promise is a way to **observe** an asynchronous process that is **already in progress.** By the time you have a promise, the process it's reporting the result of is already underway.¹ It's the call to `fs.readdir` that starts the process, not calling `then` on a promise. (And even if it were, you *are* calling `then` on the promise from `fs.readdir` right away, in your `innerAsync` function.)

If you want to wait to start the operations, wait to call the methods starting the operations and giving you the promises. I'd show an edited version of your code, but it's not clear to me what it's supposed to do, particularly since `controllerAsync` only looks at the first element of the array and doesn't wait for anything to complete before returning.

---

A couple of other notes:

1. It's almost never useful to combine `async`/`await` with explicit calls to `.then` as in `innerAsync`. That function would be more clearly written as:

   ```typescript
   async function innerAsync(n: number) {
       const value = await fs.promises.readdir(".");
       console.log(`Executed ${n}:`, value);
       return value;
   }
   ```

   From an order-of-operations perspective, that does exactly the same thing as the version with the explicit `then`.
2. There's no purpose served by declaring `controllerAsync` as an `async` function, since it never uses `await`. The only reason for making a function `async` is so you can use `await` within it.

---

¹ This is true in the normal case (the vast majority of cases), including the case of the promises you get from Node.js' `fs/promises` methods. There are (or were), unfortunately, a couple of libraries that had functions that returned promises but didn't start the actual work until the promise's `then` method was called. But those were niche outliers and arguably violate the semantics of promises.

Comment: Oh my, that makes totally sense! Wrapping it in a function to be explicitly called/executed when needed solves this (`async () => innerAsync(n)`).  This makes it much more simple to understand. Thanks for that, and also for the additional notes!

Comment: @nkmol - It's a pleasure. Thanks for teaching me about `timers/promises`. :-)

Answer (score 2):

> What causes the other, seemingly unused, promises to be executed?

A promise is a tool used to watch *something* and provide an API to react to the *something* being complete.

Your `innerAsync` function calls `fs.promises.readdir`. Calling `fs.promises.readdir` makes *something* happen (reading a directory).

The `then` callback is called as a reaction when reading that directory is complete.

(It isn't clear why you marked `innerAsync` as `async` and then **didn't** use `await` inside it.)

If you **don't** use `then` or `await`, then that doesn't change the fact you have called `fs.promises.readdir`!

> How can I make sure in this snippet only the first Promise is executed, where the others stay pending?

Focus on the function which *does* the thing, not the code which handles it being complete.

---

Or an analogy:

If you tell Alice to go to the shops and get milk, but don't tell Bob to put the milk in the fridge when Alice gets back, then you shouldn't be surprised that Alice has gone to the shops and come back with milk.

Comment: Thank you for this great explanation! I which I could accept both your answers :) I was able to solve the 'issue' by wrapping the function call in an extra function (`async () => innerAsync(n)`). Thank you very much!