# How to import a Promise but not execute it immediately?

Tags: javascript, promise

I am trying to create a modules which is returning a Promise, and here is my test code.

I have a test promise module:

```
const test = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
console.log('loaded promise test');
resolve(true);
});

export default test;
```

And I import it to my index:

```
import test from "./test.js";

console.log('end');
```

Then I have a result like this:

```
loaded promise test
end
```

What I actually want is to execute the promise where I need rather than at the very beginning.
Or maybe I can just import a prototype of the promise and new it when I want it, how can I do that?

Comment: Creating a promise starts the function immediately. If you don't want to do that, export a function that creates the promise rather than exporting the promise itself.

Comment: [^^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77732850/how-to-import-a-promise-but-not-execute-it-immediately#comment137039300_77732850) The executor function you pass to `new Promise` is executed immediately and synchronously. Its purpose is to start the asynchronous process the promise will report the completion of. There has to be a dupetarget to point this at. There [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74796407/unawaited-promises-still-executed), but...

Comment: A promise is not something you can "execute". It's a result value. Use a function if you want to run code at (multiple) arbitrary times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i remember using that when i created a repository for database operations
i used a functions that has a promise inside it

the Promise is immediately invoked when it is created, so that's why i have wrapped it with a function, because it doesn't invoke immediately until you call it your self

remember to make the function returns the promise as well like below:

```js
const test = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    console.log('loaded promise test');
    resolve(true);
  });
}

export default test;

// other file
import {test} from 'test-file-path'

// to invoke test you have to use it like that

test()

//also use it with await because it is asynchronous code like that

await test()
```

also you can use try catch block inside it for catch error and reject it

```js
const test = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    try{
      console.log('loaded promise test');
      resolve(true);
    }catch(error){
      reject(error.message)
    }
  });
}
```